# On the (wrong?) interpretation of log-linear models

Tags: interpretation, linear, log-linear

For simplicity, let $X$ be a continuous random variable and assume that
${E}[\ln(Y)|X] = \beta X$, i.e., the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X$ is proportional to $X$. 
According to many questions/answers on the interpretation of log-linear models, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+interpretation+log, the common interpretation is that $\exp(\beta)-1$ denotes the expected percentage change in $Y$ if $X$ is increased by one unit. 
(If $\beta\approx 0$, we have that  $\exp(\beta)-1\approx \beta$, so $\beta$ has a direct interpretation in the aforementioned sense)

However,
\begin{align*}
\beta &= {E}[\ln(Y)|X=x+1]-E[\ln(Y)|X=x] \neq \ln(E[Y|X=x+1])-\ln(E[Y|X=x]) 
\\
&= \ln\left(
\frac{E[Y|X=x+1]}{E[Y|X=x]}\right),
\end{align*}
where the inequality follows due to Jensen's inequality.
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\exp(\beta)-1 \neq \frac{E[Y|X=x+1]-E[Y|X=x]}{E[Y|X=x]}.
\end{align*}

Am I missing something?

**Update:** 
To get a better understanding where the possible problem arises, note that there is a random variable $U$, with $E[U|X]=0$, such that
$\ln(Y)=\beta X + U$. Thus, it follows that 
\begin{align*}
E[Y|X] = E[\exp(\beta X +U)|X] = \exp(\beta X)E[\exp(U)|X].
\end{align*}
If we now **assume** that $E[\exp(U)|X]$ is constant (a.s), we obtain
\begin{align*}
\ln\left(
\frac{E[Y|X=x+1]}{E[Y|X=x]}\right) & = 
\ln\left(
\frac{\exp(\beta(x+1))E[\exp(U)|X=x+1]}{\exp(\beta x)E[\exp(U)|X=x]}\right)
\\
& \stackrel{E[\exp(U)|X]=1}{=}\beta.
\end{align*}
Thus, the first inequality above becomes an equality and the interpretation of $\exp(\beta)-1$ as the expected percentage change follows.

**However**, assuming $E[\exp(U)|X]$ is a constant is not valid, in general. Obviously, it is true if $U$ and $X$ are independent, but in general the conditional expectation of $\exp(U)$ depends on $X$.
Hence, in general, we have that
\begin{align*}
\ln\left(
\frac{E[Y|X=x+1]}{E[Y|X=x]}\right) & = 
\ln\left(
\frac{\exp(\beta(x+1))E[\exp(U)|X=x+1}{\exp(\beta x)E[\exp(U)|X=x]}\right)
\\
& \stackrel{E[\exp(U)|X]=1}{=}\beta+\ln\left(
\frac{E[\exp(U)|X=x+1}{E[\exp(U)|X=x]}\right)
\\ & =: \beta + g(x+1,x).
\end{align*}
So,
\begin{align*}
\frac{E[Y|X=x+1]-E[Y|X=x]}{E[Y|X=x]} = \exp(\beta) exp(g(x+1,x))-1.
\end{align*}

Concluding, I only get the ``common'' interpretation of $\exp(\beta)-1$ when I assume that $E[\exp(U)|X]$ is a constant?

Comment: It's not quite "if $X$ is increased by 1 unit", it's an infinitesimal increase in $X$.  So you should think of it as a derivative at $X$ rather than as a slope over a specific finite interval of $X$ [$X$, $X+1$]..   As you have discovered, with a nonlinear function, the two are not the same (well, hardly ever!)

Comment: @van_der_span Please merge your accounts so you can more easily edit your posts. See how to do that in the [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.